# Install Wordpress and replace old OAK cms

Tags: wordpress

Can you please help me. I have a hosting server and I only have `FTP` access. There is `OAK` cms installed at the hosting machine `WWW` directory and this old CMS is hosting a page in production.

I would like to ask what is the proper way to install `Wordpress` to this machine without shut down the old webpage. Should I install WordPress to a subdirectory? If yes, then how can I forward all the request to the new subdirectory? unfortunately 
I don't have access to the DNS server to modify it.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you must install Wordpress in a subdirectory. You can go through this link for a step by step explanation: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-in-a-subdirectory-step-by-step/

Comment: Thank you. But how can I redirect all the traffic to the sub directory after I set up WP? Should I modify httpaccess file?

Comment: Yes, in the link I gave; there is explanation of that too. Yes, you must modify the .htaccess file.

Comment: Ok the htacces file in your tutorial will redirect all the traffic from root directory to the sub directory? So if the user type mydomain.com in the browser then the user will see mydomain.com/subdomain in the browser.. right?